# Objective C: Controlling Fixed Space Bar Button Item

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad, uiinterfaceorientation

I am doing some exercises for me to be familiar with XCode and Objective C in preparation for my final school project and for my app. I am having a problem regarding the spacing of my buttons in my toolbar when the orientation changes.

I set a Fixed Space Bar Button Item in-between the buttons and set it to zero on portrait and want to expand it on landscape orientation so it will accommodate the whole toolbar.

How can I do that? Is it possible to control the Fixed Space Bar Button Item programmatically when the orientation changes?

Is there another way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Override `willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:duration:` on your view controller.

In this method remove the Fixed space bar button and replace it with an flexible bar button item.

Answer (score 0):

You dont have to put fixed spaces bar button.
just remove the fixed space bar button with the flexible bar button.
and you app should support orientation.
then when you will rotate it it will automatically adjust the spaces in between